# TensorBoard ValueError: Expected scalar shape, saw shape: (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

When I use the callback function TensorBoard as the following:

```
skip_training = False

tensorboad_cb = TensorBoard('logs')

def train_model(model, callbacks_list):
    '''
    Input: 
        Model and callback list,
    Return: 
        Model with best-checkpoint weights.
    '''
    ## TYPE YOUR CODE for task 10 here:
    #history = model.fit(X_tr, y_tr, batch_size=4096, epochs=20, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_va, y_va), callbacks=[callbacks_list])
    if not skip_training:
      history = model.fit(X_tr, y_tr, batch_size=4096, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=[tensorboad_cb])
      model.save(checkpoint_name)
    else:
      model = load_model(checkpoint_name)
    return model

model = train_model(model, callbacks_list)
```

I get this error:

> 287/287 [==============================] - 180s 626ms/step - loss:
> 0.1103 - f1_score: 0.6010 - acc: 0.9565
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 17     return model
> 18
> ---> 19 model = train_model(model, callbacks_list)
> 20
> 21 #history = model.fit(train_data, epochs=15, validation_data=valid_data, validation_steps=50,
> callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
>
> 9 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/check_ops.py
> in assert_scalar(tensor, name, message)    2282       if
> context.executing_eagerly():    2283         raise
> ValueError('%sExpected scalar shape, saw shape: %s.'
> -> 2284                          % (message or '', shape,))    2285       else:    2286         raise ValueError('%sExpected scalar shape for
> %s, saw shape: %s.'
>
> ValueError: Expected scalar shape, saw shape: (1,).

Comment: Can you share complete code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you.Thanks!

Comment: Having the same issue on TensorFlow 2.7.0, any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue on tensorflow 2.6.2, but on tensorflow 2.4.1 it works well.

finally, I fixed it by comment the code:

[comment tensorboard code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5go6N.png)

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30906785)